# What is best use of static in Java

Tags: java, oop, variables, static

I read couple of comments by the developers on other threads regarding use of static variable:

1. It costs memory: Is there a way to release memory occupied by static variables when we exit from the class where they were defined/created?
2. Whats the difference between using static against static final variables in terms of memory management in case you couldn't avoid using it.

I understand that using static is against OOPS concepts, memory management is poor, defeating the concept of encapsulation. If I use 5-6 static variables will the impact be so big that I literally have to stop using it. Or may be someone from you guys can suggest me the actual use of static in Java an object oriented programming language?

Comment: What do you mean by "exit from the class"? If you mean when one method happens to finish, no that certainly won't release any memory. If you only want a variable for the duration of a method, it should be a local variable... but you should be worrying about the design rather than memory use, IMO. Show us the code that you're worrying about...

Comment: Don't throw the baby out with the bathwater. Static has its uses, but I think the biggest argument against **over**-use is not memory issues but loss of OOP benefits by risking increased cyclomatic complexity. But having said this, I'm voting to close the question as opinion based as it's just going to engender a long winded debate.

Comment: you may visualize static variables as **global variables**. They don't correspond to any single object, but to class as a whole.

Comment: `static` and `final` are totally different things.. You are asking multiple questions here..

Answer (score 1):

> It costs memory: Is there a way to release memory occupied by static
>   variables when we exit from the class where they were defined/created?

Ok. Point 1 --> All variables *irrespective* of *static or otherwise* occupy memory. So *it costs memory* is not exactly accurate.

Next, the difference between *static and instance* variables lies in when they become *unreachable* (ready for GC). instance level instances become *unreachable* when you go out of their scope but with instances referred by static references, they will be reachable unless explicitly set to `null`.

So,

```
static Object o = new Object();
o=null ;
```

doesn't keep the object in memory. If not set to `null` *explicitly*, the instance pointed to by `o` will linger around until the class in which it is defined gets GCed which happens when the class loader which loaded this class gets GCed (provided the reference has not escaped).

> defeating the concept of encapsulation.

static fields don't defeat encapsulation. Encapsulation is basically not allowing access to internal structures. There can be multiple arguments on this point, so I will not take this up.

> If I use 5-6 static variables will the impact be so big that I
>   literally have to stop using it.

Again, it comes down to point 1. *Static* is a **design choice** rather than an *implementation choice*. In my opinion, use *static* as a lost option.

Answer (score 0):

It's debatable.

Ideally you want to have static the things that are common to all the instances, i.e. that are related to the concept of the class rather than to the single instance (ex. Integer.parseInt() ).

Static final variables / constant kinda relate to it for example for default values (Dog.defaultNumberOfLegs=4).

Static mutable things are trickier, and are, imho, an hacky shorthand for having a shared state. Good for quick experimentation, but rather bad to keep in your production code, as static stuff becomes hard to test with, due to the increasing difficulty in mocking it. If you want things to be unique, you should make a singleton out of it once you move to real production code.

That aside, 5 or 6 variables shouldn't be too much of a memory hassle. It's more related to elegance/mantainability/testability. This is for all "normal" cases. If you really put yourself into it, you can create chain of references with a single static variable that will clog your memory, but it's not a realistic scenario.

Comment: `"It's debatable"` -- which is why the question as a whole should be closed and deleted.

Comment: The question is actually multiple questions. The first part is debatable, the part where he asks "will 5 or 6 static be too much of a memory clog?" is, imho, a non-debatable "no".